# C++ interface inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

how can I do this derivation in C++? 
(the current example doesn't work)

```
  struct IB
    {

    };

    struct IDerivedB : public IB
    {

    };

    struct IA
    {
    public:
        virtual IB Foo(const string& type) = 0;
    };

    struct IDerivedA : public IA
    {
    public:
        virtual IDerivedB Foo(const string& type) override = 0;
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your compiler tell you ? I assume it says more than "it doesn't work"

Answer (score 6):

Return type covariance applies to pointers and references only, this should work:

```
struct IB
{

};

struct IDerivedB : public IB
{

};

struct IA
{
public:
    virtual IB* BuildPresenter(const string& type) = 0;
};

struct IDerivedA : public IA
{
public:
    virtual IDerivedB* BuildPresenter(const string& type) override = 0;
};
```

Comment: Great! It makes sense, now, can i do it with shared_ptr instead of regular pointers?

Comment: @Adibe7 not directly, no. But you can make current `BuildPresenter` protected and make a public `BuildPresenterShared`  that calls `BuildPresenter`, wraps pointer in a `shared_ptr` and returns that (it needs not be virtual). This has to be done for each class in the hierarchy though.